# Selecting top x categories with their top x products

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which selects the top 3 records per category. At the moment it limits the records to 9. However, this is not right because if I limit the number to 8 the last subcategory loses one record from display.

I want to limit the records per SubCategories queried number i.e. 3 subcategories only with their top 3 products.

What I have is the following:

```
SELECT TOP 9 *
FROM tProduct p
WHERE p.ProductID IN (
    SELECT TOP 3 ProductID
    FROM tProduct PP
    WHERE pp.SubCategoryID = p.SubCategoryID 
    )
ORDER BY SubCategoryID
```

Any ideas how to modify the above?

Edit: The closest I got so far based on the `CROSS APPLY` as suggested is this:

```
SELECT * FROM tSubCategory c
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(3) *

    FROM tProduct p
    WHERE
        c.SubCategoryID = p.SubCategoryID
    ORDER BY
        p.ProductID DESC
) x
WHERE c.SubCategoryID BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

However, the query should specify only one number i.e. 4 categories and not between 1 and 2 which applies to the subcategory id.

Comment: Can you provide recodsets that what you have now, with limit value 9, and that you expect when limit is 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT TOP(3) * FROM tSubCategory) c
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP(3) *
    FROM tProduct p
    WHERE c.SubCategoryID = p.SubCategoryID
    ORDER BY p.ProductID DESC
) x;
```

...where I've based just wrapped your tSubCategory into a subquery to limit it to just three rows.

Comment: Yes my clever new friend!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an example for CROSS APPLY as mention by Rob Farley here:
http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/04/13/the-power-of-t-sqls-apply-operator/

For this particular query, you would want to selct tthe top 3 subcategory rows and then use OUTER APPLY to append that to each product row. You will not be able to use top 9 on the select however, as that will take 9 rows only (as opposed to the top 9 product ids). This will need to be done with a WHERE clause. The query below (with some column name modifications) should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product AS p
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT TOP (3) s.description 
    FROM SubCategory AS s
    WHERE s.ID = p.subcategoryId 
    GROUP BY s.id, s.description 
    ORDER BY s.id DESC) as s 
  WHERE p.Id IN (select distinct top 9 Id from Product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the window functions.  I'm not sure exactly what you want for the output, but the following should be pretty close:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ProductId order by SubCategoryId) as sc_seqnum,
             dense_rank() over (order by ProductId) as p_seqnum
      FROM tProduct p
     ) p
WHERE sc_seqnum <= 3 and -- number of subcategories per product 
      p_seqnum <= 3  -- number of products to show
```

Comment: Gordon, your query returns only 3 records. The correct scenario would be If I choose 3 subcategories and their top 3 products I should get 9 records in total. Also, from in query if I change the the sc_seqnum to any other number the results do not change.

Comment: You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I don't fully understand what is being limited how, but I am pretty sure that `row_number()` and `dense_rank()` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this is the perfect case to use `CROSS APPLY`.

Read more here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607246/Making-OUTER-and-CROSS-APPLY-work-for-you

Please look at very first use case.